# How is attributing a double to an int even possible in this case?

Tags: c, math.h

I just started learning C and I'm having trouble understanding why the following code even works at all:

```
void convertMyNumber (float myValue) {
    int myNewValue = floor(myValue * 100);
    printf("%d", myNewValue);
}
```

Looking at the documentation for math.h, it is stated that the `floor()` function takes a `double` as an argument, and also returns a `double`. So far so great, I just ran the above code and typed in `576.73` as the value for the `myValue` variable. Surprisingly (to me), it printed out exactly `57673` on the screen, and I'm finding it difficult to understand how it is possible that it was able to attribute the returning value of the `floor` function (a `double`) to `int myNewValue`.

Comment: Read about [*implicit conversions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

Answer (score 2):

This line `int myNewValue = floor(myValue * 100);` contains no less than 3 implicit conversions.

- In `myValue * 100`, the integer constant `100` is of type `int`. An implicit conversion known as *"the usual arithmetic conversions"* convert the `int` operand to `float`. The multiplication is carried out on `float` and the resulting type is `float`. See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).
- The `float` result from the previous calculation is converted to the type of the function's operand. Function parameters are implicitly converted "as if by assignment", converting the passed argument to the type of the parameter, in this case `double`.
- The result of `double` is converted by assignment to the type of the left operand `int`. If the `double` contains a value which can be represented by an `int`, this conversion is well-defined.

So this is why it works, but relying on implicit conversions is often not a good idea, since the potential for accidental bugs is great.

Answer (score 0):

In an assignment, value of the right-hand side operand is implicitly converted into the type of left-hand side operand. That's how `floor(576.73 * 100) = 57673.0` became `57673`. C does this by taking the double value and ignoring (truncating) its fractional part.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment what you are looking at is an [implicit](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-c/), or eqyivalently, automatic type conversion that is done by the compiler. The example below shows how you could perform the conversion explicitly, also called "type casting".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void f_to_i(float f);

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
  float fl = 576.73;
  f_to_i(fl);
}

void f_to_i(float f)
{
  int i;
  // Implicit Conversion
  i = floor(f * 100);
  printf("%d\n", i);
  i = 0;
  // Explicit Conversion
  i = (int)floor(f * 100);
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```